# R Shiny: when doing withProgress, pop a message on timeout

Tags: r, shiny

An example of `withProgress` for fetching data:

```
 withProgress({
     data <- dbGetQuery(con, query)
 }, value = 1, message = 'Fetching data...')
```

Assume this usually returns the data fairly quickly. However, in some cases, when the database is overloaded, the query might get stacked in a queue, which would result in an unusually long waiting time for the results.

Is it possible to add a timeout and a warning pop-up, alerting the user that the wait time is normal (i.e., expected, if say the reported load is high), all is running fine and there is no need to, for example, restart the app?

I think it would be enough to change the `message =` after running 60s, but is it possible?

Comment: Using shinyalert would give you the pop-up you are looking for, you just need to find a way for the delay

Comment: Just a comment on your approch: executing the db-query in an async process can avoid blocking the ui in the first place. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52863720/async-display-progress-when-actionbutton-is-hit-and-disable-other-operations-fo/53005788#53005788).

Comment: @ismirsehregal thanks, will take a look