# R future: show progress + wait until done

Tags: r, shiny, parallel-processing, ipc, future

I'm using the R package `future` to run a large compute job. I would like to parallelize the job across three cores and have a separate progress bar for each core. I would also like the script to wait until all three cores are done before displaying the `Done!` message.

Right now the `Done!` message appears while the cores are still running. If I use a function like `resolved` then the progress bars show 0% until the three cores are done and then immediately skip to 100%. How can I update progress and wait for completion at the same time?

For context, I'm uploading a large number of files to AWS S3.

```
library(shiny)
library(future)
plan(multiprocess)

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("run","Run")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    observeEvent(input$run, {
        # Start three parallel processes.
        progress <- list()
        for(k in 1:3) {
            progress[[k]] <- AsyncProgress$new(session, min=1, max=15)
            future({
                for (i in 1:15) {
                    progress[[k]]$set(value = i)
                    Sys.sleep(0.5)
                }
                progress[[k]]$close()
            })
        }
        # Show notification when all three processes are done.
        showNotification("Done!", type = "error") # this runs too early
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The [quick-start guide](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/fellstat/ipc/blob/master/inst/doc/shinymp.html) of the ipc-package gives an example of what you are asking for: AsyncProgress.

Comment: Are you referring to the `Changing a reactive value from a future` example? It looks like they're using `renderTable()` to wait for the output. I'm curious if there's a way to do this within a reactive expression. For example, wait until cores finish running before move on to the next line.

Comment: Just below the example you mentioned, you'll find another one called: *Adding a progress bar to an async operation*. Please also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52863720/async-display-progress-when-actionbutton-is-hit-and-disable-other-operations-fo).

Answer (score 0):

You can use futures returning a result, that you store in a reactive value initially `NULL`. Then show the notification when the three reactive values are not `NULL`.

```r
library(shiny)
library(future)
library(promises)
plan(multisession)
library(ipc)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("run","Run")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  results <- replicate(3, reactiveVal(), simplify = FALSE)

  observeEvent(input$run, {
    progress <- vector("list", 3)
    lapply(1:3, function(k) {
      progress[[k]] <- AsyncProgress$new(session, message = paste0("job ", k))
      future({
        for(i in 1:15) {
          progress[[k]]$inc(1/15)
          Sys.sleep(0.5)
        }
        progress[[k]]$close()
        18 # result
      }) %...>% (results[[k]])
    })
    NULL
  })
  
  observe({
    resultsList <- list(results[[1]](), results[[2]](), results[[3]]())
    n <- length(Filter(Negate(is.null), resultsList))
    if(n == 3) {
      showNotification("Done!")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```